# Laravel MongoDB: Point must only contain numeric elements

Tags: mongodb, laravel-5

I am trying to use my own set or coordinates for GeoWithin

```
$users = User::where('location', 'geoWithin', [
   '$geometry' => [
       'type' => 'Polygon',
       'coordinates' => [[
           $shop->bounds
       ]],
    ], 
]);
```

However, this is the error I am getting: Point must only contain numeric elements. $shop->bounds is an array of coordinates. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try convert $shop->bounds to double.